# DB Design: multiple values for single field in a record

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I am working on an auto-suggest feature and as part of it I want to weight the results based on a particular user's preference. For example: If most of my users frequently type in `fish`, then the algorithm will return `fish` as the most popular result once the user types `f`. However, if a particular user mostly types in `food`, then I want to apply a weight such that it takes that particular user's preference into account.

I initially thought of doing this by having a large auto-suggest index, with a field `userids` and whenever a user types in a letter, the algorithm would check if that particular user's userid was present in the `userids` field and if present would apply a corresponding weight to that particular result.

A few records would look like:

```
word             |count            |userids
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
food             |2                |aa,b,ccd
fish             |12               |a,b,c,d,e,f,gg,he,jkl,sd
```

However, I do not think this is an approach that would scale all that well with even a few hundred active users. What would be a better way to design this DB?

Thanks in advance,
asleepysamurai

P.S. I'm a newbie when it comes to DB design, so please explain your solution in layman terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a good idea. The table is not [normalized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) and you will end up with complicated queries when you need to join on this field.

A better design is to have a `wordid` field on this table as a primary key (identifying the word) and a many to many table to connect words with users (`words_to_users` with a `wordid` and `userid` fields).

Comment: I realise this is not a good idea, which is why I asked for better ideas. Could you please tell how you would go about designing such a db?

Comment: I completely agree. Although storing a comma separated list *might* seem easy at the beginning it will cause a *lot* of trouble in the long run

Comment: @asleepysamurai - And which is why I suggested one.

Comment: Okay so you want me to use a normalized table? I'll look into it and get back to you. Also what degree of normalization would you suggest? 3rd degree?

Comment: Thanks for the added explanation. It fits my needs perfectly.

Comment: @asleepysamurai - My suggestion it to try to go to BCNF or 3NF at the least.